# Firebase write to database after upload action to storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to upload a image to firebase storage using job scheduler. After the upload action, I have tried to write the download url to firebase database using the referece.setValue(downloadUrl) in OnSuccessListener of the upload task.

I am upload image to storage like this

```
        val directory = context.getDir("images", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val file = File("${directory.absolutePath}/$storyKey")
        file.mkdirs()

        val fileUri = android.net.Uri.fromFile(java.io.File(file, "$imageName.jpg"))

        val task = storageReference.child(fileUri.lastPathSegment).putFile(fileUri)
        task.addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
            imageUploadStatus = true
            val downloadUrl = snapshot.downloadUrl
            reference.child(key).child("downloadUrl").setValue(downloadUrl)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    imageUploadStatus = false
                    exception.printStackTrace()
                }
```

But I keep getting crash like this

```
E/UncaughtException:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbw(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                                   at com.example.images.jobs.ImageUploadJob$onRunJob$1.onSuccess(ImageUploadJob.kt:107)
                                                                                   at com.example.images.jobs.ImageUploadJob$onRunJob$1.onSuccess(ImageUploadJob.kt:30)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzaa.run(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: What's the value of the `key` variable?

Comment: It's the push id from firebase

Comment: But has it been intialized by the time you call `setValue()`?

Comment: Yes it is, I have checked it.

Comment: You forgot to include the actual error message (typically contained in a "caused by" in the stack trace). But my best guess is that `downloadUrl` it causing problems. Since [`getDownloadUrl` returns a `URI`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getDownloadUrl()), you might want to try `.setValue(downloadUrl.toString())`.

Comment: I cannot believe converting it to string was the answer. Since setValue() accepted Any type, I assumed Uri worked. and as for "caused by" in stack trace. I didn't find any, that what made it weird. I got 3 or 4 repetition of the above stack trace that's all. with no caused by in it, and also if possible can is good to use Job schedulers to handle offline storage upload or is there any better way?